# htaccess rewrite rule not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a url for a clients website but it isn't working as expected.

I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

```
RewriteRule ^about/sectionreps/(.*)$ http://myclientssite.com/sectionreps/ [r=301,nc]
```

So, /sectionreps/ will redirect to /about/sectionreps/ but that isn't what I want.

Here is the whole file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about/sectionreps/(.*)$ http://myclientssite.com/sectionreps/ [r=301,nc]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So my question is why is url rewrite not going from:
http://myclientssite.com/about/sectionreps

to

http://myclientssite.com/sectionreps/

Comment: What's the question?  You only mentioned where you didn't want something to redirect

Comment: oops, edited my question.

Comment: Is it for just this page? Or can you change permalink structure within wp-admin?

Comment: Its a child of admin they way the previous agency built the site restricts me from doing so :-/  But a compromise has been made with the client now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code says that `/about/sectionreps/*` will be redirected to (possibly another site) `/sectionreps/`. Not the other way around, as you implied (but contradicted later in the post). Is that redirection what you're looking for?

Your code requires a trailing / on the input URI. That could be why `/about/sectionreps` isn't matching (but `/about/sectionreps/` should).

```
RewriteRule ^about/sectionreps(/)?  /sectionreps  [R=301,NC]
```

should do the job. You don't need to match the trailing stuff `(.*)$`, since you're discarding it, and you don't need to give the http: bit since you're on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

try add this code below the wordpress code

```
#start custom redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myclientssite.com/about/sectionreps/  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myclientssite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 / http://www.myclientssite.com/sectionreps/
#end custom redirects
```

Comment: Let me know how that goes for you

Comment: This sadly sent it into a never ending /sectionreps/sectionsreps/ etc But never mind, my client is happy for the full url now so long as /sectionreps redirects to the correct page which it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about/sectionreps(/.*)?$ /sectionreps/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Make sure to test in a new browser.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. My client has come to a compromise instead due to a tight deadline.